# ONS Toolbar in ANDROID

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, onsen-ui

i am designing a page in mobile app using ONSEN UI.
in page, i have used onsen toolbar. the problem i am facing is the text i am writing doesn't come in center even if i write that using center class.
i tried some alternative solutions like, "text-allign=center",  text , but none worked. 
please show me some way using which i can keep text in center. 
p.s. - i am developing the app in android environment, have tested the app on emulator and device both. 
here is the code i have written for toolbar.

```
     <ons-toolbar style="background-color:#000;opacity:0.5; ">       
         <div class="center" style="color:white">Some Text</div> 
    </ons-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute `fixed-style` to center the toolbar on Android:

```
<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
  <div class="center">
    Centered title
  </div>
</ons-toolbar>
```

The reason why it isn't centered on Android is that for native Android apps the title is often left-aligned. Of course, there are exceptions.